# C# string passed as an function argument

Tags: c#

```
string myString;

void WriteString( string myString ) // This myString is copied. 
{
    // Writing to myString. 
    myString[0] = 'b'; // chaning this is just changing copy
}


void ReadString( string myString ) // Is this myString copied, eventhough I'm not writing at all?
{
   if( myString[0] == 'a' ) // calling just get property in string
      DebugConsole.Write("I just read myString and first character was 'a'");
}
```

Hello. I wonder if, in the case above, compiler would distinguish two functions and try to optimize ReadString function by passing myString as reference or inlining the function. If that is not the case, what should be done if myString is too huge to just ignore copying?

Thank you.

Comment: Strings in C# are immutable. `myString[0] = 'b';` does not compile.

Comment: Strings are reference types in .NET. So passing them around passes the reference around, and no copies are made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the compiler's optimizations (which, no, would not make all that much of a difference anyway here), the `string` type in C# is always passed by reference.

Furthermore, the `string` reference is immutable. That means that your `WriteString` function wouldn't compile in the first place.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(myString);
builder[0] = 'b';
myString = builder.ToString();
```

Note, of course, that this solution will not change any references to the `string` made outside the function. In order to do that, pass it as a `ref` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for a kind answer to a dumb question. Get to read more before ask I guess.